# Is there a way to get all Contacts without specific criteria?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, infusionsoft

Using the Infusionsoft gem, is there a way to get all Contacts through the Infusionsoft API without a specific criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the wildcard as a query parameter for the Id field:

```
query = {"Id" => "%"}
selected_fields = %w(Id FirstName LastName ...)
data = Infusionsoft.data_query("Contacts", 1000, 0 , query, selected_fields)
```

The API will return an array of hashes, each one representing the contact with the selected fields as keys.

As per yuga's comment, if you have more than 1000 contacts, you will need to add a loop for data pagination:

```
contacts = []
i = 0
query = {"Id" => "%"}
selected_fields = %w(Id FirstName LastName ...)

loop do 
  data = Infusionsoft.data_query("Contacts", 1000, i , query, selected_fields)
  break if data.empty?
  contacts.concat(data)
  i += 1
end
```

Comment: As the results are limited to 1000, you would need to repeat this request in a loop, incrementing the third parameter of data_query() on each step. I'm not writing in ruby, so leaving it up to you.